# Foursquare places

Tags: api, foursquare

We would like to be able to pull out certain places from foursquare an categorize them on our website along with comments from foursquare users. I have the following questions:

1- Can we pull out places and categorize them the way we want on our website? e.g: restaurants/bar/lounge/club/landmarks/others.

2- can we pull out as well phone numbers (when available) and addresses (longitude-lattitude) of places ?

3- Does foursquare have any general descriptive summaries of each place?

Thanks for the help. 
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Foursquare has an API, more information can be found at this [link](https://developer.foursquare.com/)

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, check out the [Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues) in 4sq API, specifically, the [search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search). When you query the API, as part of the result set for each venue, you get a category
2. If available, you will get them back under the 'contact' field, check out the [response venue object](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue) from the search function
3. Yes, description field, you will need to make an [API request](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) to get the complete venue object.
4. Edit: one last thing, [attribute and play nice](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/attribution) :)

From my experience, you do not get a lot of venues with 'contact' and 'description' information. But foursquare is not very popular where I test my application, so it might be bad experience - experiment with it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

FourSquare has a great category tree that you can use for categorizing restaurants

http://aboutfoursquare.com/foursquare-categories/

Actually, I'm using this tree in my website:
[Dishes Map](http://www.dishesmap.com)